# Не могу заставить бота на пользователе VK читать сообщения

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

Делаю бота для пользователя вк
Нужно, чтобы бот в ответ на сообщение отвечал стикером, и кидал в ЧС - это я умею.
Однако, как бы я не старался, не могу сделать так, чтобы он мог читать сообщения через лонгпул. Вот, собственно, сам код:

```
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import vk_api
import requests

token = "токен от пользователя вк"
v = 5.103
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token, api_version=v)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
try:
    vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
    print(error_msg)
print("бот запустился")
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:   
        if 'запретное слово' in event.text:
            if event.from_user:
                vk.method("messages.sendSticker", {"user_id": event.user_id, "sticker_id": 50597, "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
                vk.method("account.ban", {"owner_id": event.user_id})
```

Код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\yumabot.py", line 8, in <module>
    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\vk_api\longpoll.py", line 517, in __init__
    self.update_longpoll_server()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\vk_api\longpoll.py", line 531, in update_longpoll_server
    response = self.vk.method('messages.getLongPollServer', values)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 656, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: no access to call this method
```

Answer (score 1):

Как я вижу, у вас отсутствует *Standalone-приложение*, где необходим тот самый токен. Именно он имеет доступ к разделу **Messages**, без этого - бесполезно, можно просто будет стикеры слать, обычный текст.